# How to enter a level when touching an object

Tags: unity, 3d, javascript, gameobject

I am working on a project in Unity 4.6.1f1 and I was wondering how can I make a cube touch another cube to go to the next level (the image below)?

[image: touchcube]!

**EDIT:** I made a script and put it on the purple cube then enabled "is trigger" on the purple cube, but the blue cube goes right through it.

Inspector:

[image: inspector]

And the code:

[image: code]

**EDIT 5/15/15:** I edited my script and I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LevelCollider is attached to a Collider that is a trigger. That means it will not call OnCollisionEnter. It will call OnTriggerEnter.

Try adding this to LevelCollider:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
     Application.LoadLevel("Level1");
}
```

That should do ya!

Answer (score 2):

Detect collisions with OnCollisionEnter then load your level there. I.e.:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Level1");
}
```

If your character's Collider is a trigger, then you need to use OnTriggerEnter. I.e.:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Level1");
}
```

If neither of these work, try checking these things:

- The character and object are set to collide in the [layer collision matrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).
- The scene called "Level1" is
  added to the build. You can check if it is by pressing Ctrl-Shift-B
  under 'Scenes in build'.

Answer (score 0):

The command to load a level is [Application.LoadLevel()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html). Call that from an "On Collision" function on the cube.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a box collider (`Add` -> `Physics` -> `Box Collider`) in the inspector.

Then, add a script with a function

```
 OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
```

then add that script to the cube you want to collide with.

More info in here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers

Comment: Is this in JavaScript?

Comment: Do I create that function then put Application.LoadLevel() in it?

Comment: It is c#. And yes, you put Application.LoadLevel() inside the function

Comment: I enabled "is trigger" on the collider settings (for the cube that's supposed to take you to the next level) with Application.LoadLevel() and all it does is go right through the cube without leaving the scene.

Comment: That Cube has the script added to itself? Post some screenshots of code and inspector

Comment: I added the screenshots.

Comment: @kprovost7314 click on Edit Collider and check if all the cube is surrounded by it

Comment: The whole cube is surrounded by it.

Comment: Do the other cube also has a collider? Running out of options here!

Comment: Yes but I notice something. It says "Script error: OnCollisionEnter This message has to be of type: Collision".

Comment: @kprovost7314 check your function, it has to be like this: "void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)" . You have Collider instead of Collision

Comment: Replace other with Collision too?

Comment: the "other" is the variable name, so that doesnt matter.

Comment: I changed other to Collision but that didn't work so I kept other and it still didn't work but when I used other, the error went away. Any other Ideas?

Comment: add a Debug.Log("Collided") inside the function and see if when collided, you get any feedback in Console.

Comment: I didn't get any feedback.